# Recovering the openness of a map from the openness of its scalar projections

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology, implicit-function-theorem

Good morning. I have been thinking about the following question for a while without much success, therefore I'm starting to doubt its validity, although I don't have a clear counterexample in mind.

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $F=(F_1,\dotso, F_m):X\to \mathbb R^m$ be a smooth map such that $F(0)=0$. Assume that $F$ is open at zero, i.e. for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta=\delta(\epsilon)$ such that $B(0,\delta)\subset F(B_X(0,\epsilon))$.

We consider vectors $\lambda\in S^{m-1}$ and the compositions $\Phi_\lambda:X\to \mathbb R$ defined by $\Phi_\lambda(x):= \langle\lambda, F(x)\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i F_i(x)$.

If $F$ is open at $0$, $\Phi_\lambda$ is open at zero for every $\lambda\in S^{m-1}$.

I'm now interested in the converse statement, specifically I want to pose these two questions:

1. Is it true that, under the assumption that $\Phi_\lambda:X\to \mathbb R$ is open at zero for every $\lambda\in S^{m-1}$, then also $F$ is open at zero?
2. In case point 1. is false, can we strengthen somewhat the hypotheses so that it becomes true, or is it unavoidably false?

Thanks in advance,

Gil

Comment: According to MathOverflow guidelines, there should be only one question per post. Also, your second question is too open and non-specific. So, I suggest it be deleted.

Comment: Please feel free to delete the second question if deemed not compliant to the rules. In my opinion though it is so related to the first one that opening a new post would be kind of duplicating the same question. As for the question being too generic, I would be interested in any reference pointing to a result of the type: If a map $F$ as above is open at zero along any scalar projection in $\mathbb R^{m}$ plus some other hypotheses of some kind then $F$ open at zero. I really need a starting point here, and googling has not been of any help unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand\C{\mathbb C}$The answer to Question 1 is no. Here is a counterexample: $X=\C$, $m=2$, $\R^2$ is identified with $\C$, and
$$F(z):=\exp\Big(-\frac1{|z|\,(2\pi-\arg z)\arg z}+i\arg z\Big)$$
for $z\in\C\setminus\{0\}$ with $\arg z\ne0$, with $F(z):=0$ otherwise, and with the values of $\arg z$ assumed to be in the interval $[0,2\pi)$.

Indeed, the function $F$ is smooth. The intersection of the image $F(D)$ under $F$ of any disk $D$ centered at $0$ with any non-horizontal line through $0$ contains an open interval containing $0$, and hence the projection of $F(D)$ on any such line through $0$ contains an open interval containing $0$. It is also easy to that the projection of $F(D)$ on the horizontal line through $0$ contains an open interval containing $0$.
However, $F(D)$ does not contain any open set containing $0$.

---

For an illustration, here is the image $F(D_{1/2})$ under $F$ of the disk $D_{1/2}$ of radius $1/2$ centered at $0$:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! May I ask you a clarification on the intersection of $F(D)$ with the real axis? Indeed it seems to me that $F(z)$ is real iff $\mathrm{arg}(z)\in {0,\pi}$. If $\mathrm{arg}(z)=0$ then $F(z)=0$  by definition, while if $\mathrm{arg}(z)=\pi$ then $F(z)\to 0$, with $F(z)<0$, as $|z|\to 0$. Even from your picture it is not clear to me how to see that that the projection of $F(D)$ on the horizontal line through $0$
 contains an open interval containing $0$. Could you please elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: @GilSanders : In particular, the projection of $F(D)$ on the horizontal line through $0$ contains the projection on the horizontal line through $0$ of the intersection (say $I$) of $F(D)$ with an arbitrary line through $0$ that is neither horizontal nor vertical, and the latter projection contains an open interval containing $0$ (because the intersection $I$ contains an open interval containing $0$).

Comment: @GilSanders : Also, the picture suggests that the projection of $F(D_{1/2})$ on the horizontal line through $0$ contains the open interval $(-0.8,0.4)$ on the real axis.

Comment: Thanks! I was confusing the projection of the image along a line with the intersection of the image with the line. IT's clear now.